# Webpack not rendering any content on localhost. It is attaching the script tag in html but nothing is displayed on the homepage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am new to webpack and i made a react app with index.js as the entry file and app.js as the root component being rendered. The webpack is getting build fine without error and the script tag is also being added to html file but there is not content getting rendered for App component.
The code for these files are -
index.js -

```
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {App} from './components/App';
// import { initWeb3 } from './utils/web3';

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
 app
);
```

App.js -

```
import React from 'react';

export class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> Hi there</h1>
            </div>
        )
      }
   }
```

The webpack.config.js file is -

```
        const path = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
    const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")
    const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
    const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

    var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template:__dirname+'/src/index.html',
      filename:'index.html',
      inject:'body'
    })

    const EslintOptions = {
      extensions: [`js`, `jsx`],
      exclude: [
        `/node_modules/`,
      ], // these are the options we'd previously passed in
    }

    module.exports = {
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
          fs: false,
          os:false,
          tls: false,
          net: false,
          path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
          zlib: false,
          http: false,
          https: false,
          stream: false,
          crypto: false,
        } 
      },
      entry: {
        app: __dirname+'/src/index.jsx'
      },
      externalsPresets:{node:true},
      externals:[nodeExternals()],
      output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: __dirname+'/public'
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: [
                  ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            include: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  modules: true
                }
              },
              'sass-loader'
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      target:'node',
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        //new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
        new ESLintPlugin(EslintOptions),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        //new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
        // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        //   template: './src/index.html'
        // }),
      ],
      devtool: 'eval-source-map',
        devServer: {
          
            port:3010,
            static:{
              directory: './public'
            },
            historyApiFallback: true,
            hot: true
          },
      mode: 'development'
    };
```

HTML file index.html is -

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Ethereum Ecommerce Store</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Also i am getting this error in console while running localhost.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at Object.util (app.bundle.js:245:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js:274:33)
at fn (app.bundle.js:415:21)
at eval (index.js?ce24:2:12)
at Object../node_modules/console-browserify/index.js (app.bundle.js:40:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js:274:33)
at fn (app.bundle.js:415:21)
at eval (log.js:1:41)
at Object../node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js (app.bundle.js:190:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js:274:33)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use

```
externals:[nodeExternals()]
```

in your webpack.config.js file.

Specifying it will *ask* webpack to use the nodejs (backend) `require()` to get dependencies.

Clients (browser web apis) do not provide require() as a function and hence the error on your localhost.

Removing the config shall fix the error.

Comment: thanks for answering but it is still giving the same error even after removing the line.

Comment: also remove `externalsPresets:{node:true}`, this config will not bundle the modules in node modules and instead "require" them , and that is where it will create problems on client side JS.

Comment: yes i did that too when i removed nodeExternals. Also changing target:node to target:web gives a different error. 
ERROR in Failed to load config "@ljharb" to extend from.
Referenced from: C:\Project\node_modules\object-is\.eslintrc

Comment: Yeah, removing target: node to target: web solves the problem along with the fix you suggested. eslint error is something entirely different and was solved by excluding node_modules from eslint.Thanks for help